# Enforce print-only document on the web

Tags: security, printing

I need to provide printable documents without any ability (or a very minimized ability) of the user to view or download them.

I don't even have to render the document. They could just click a text link and have it blindly print to a printer.

This can be done using native applications, but it would be far better to provide this feature from a web interface.

Some points:

1. I can encrypt the document on the server so the HTTP GET response is garbled. The client could fetch a dynamic key from the server just before print to re-assemble the data. This would prevent snooping through a web inspector.
2. I could demand the use of a browser extension that sends print jobs without presenting print preview windows.

What other ways could a user get the document? What else should I be thinking with preventing?

Comment: What exactly is your threat model? The data will have to be descrambled to send to the printer, and you have no way to tell if they are actually sending the data to a printer or saving it.

Comment: I only want someone to print it. Don't want them to print screen or copy the file in any way. I could enforce printers by name using a print extension, I suppose.

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't entirely possible, and especially not as a webserver. You cannot definitively tell where the data you're sending is going, beyond the fact that you're sending it to the client. Once you send it, you can no longer control what happens to it. The only possible way I can imagine you could do what you want would be if the printer had a private key and was able to decrypt incoming data and print it, and you encrypted your data server side and asked the client to pass it through. But you'd need printer-side support for that, which you aren't likely to get.

Comment: Yeah... this is sort of what I expected. I suppose the best approach will unfortunately be security-by-obscurity, i.e. make it as difficult as possible for a user to intercept the document. Good ideas on this are sort of what I am looking for.